# Install in unallocated Space

Tags: dual-boot, iso

How to install it in unallocated space? I have created a 100 GB space for Ubuntu. I need to install it along with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "Something else..." you will have the option to format the unallocated space to ext4 and set it as the root partition ('/').